# Subdomains in Node.js with Express for Nodejitsu

Tags: node.js, http, express, subdomain

I'd like to set up some subdomains for my Node.js app. I've built my site with express.js, and now I'd just like to throw up a little web tool on a subdomain of my site. I've tried using the vhost middleware with little luck, but am open to other approaches.

Any help would rock!

Ideally, I could just drop a new express app in a sub directory change a few lines of code, maybe change some DNS settings at it would work. The reason I'd like this is so that I can reuse a fresh instance of stylus and jade with new layouts and css styles and so forth.

Here's my normal app.js, the commented line is the attempt to use vhost.

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('view options', { layout: false });
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use('/courses', function (req, res, next) {
    var privates = require('./.private.json'),
        couch = require('nano')('https://' + privates.dbCreds.username + ':' + privates.dbCreds.password + '@wamoyo.iriscouch.com/');

  });
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/public'
  }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  // VHOST - SUBDOMAIN
  // app.use(express.vhost('adventures.innovationbound.com', require('./adventures/index').app));
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.status(404);
    res.render('four', {
      title: "Innovation Bound",
      now: new Date().getFullYear()
    });
  });
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
  });
});

app.configure('development', function() {
  app.use(express.errorHandler({
    dumpExceptions: true,
    showStack: true
  }));
});

app.configure('production', function() {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/about', routes.about);
app.get('/services', routes.services);
app.get('/events', routes.events);
app.get('/blog', routes.blog);
app.post('/contact', routes.contact);

// Courses
// app.get('/heartbeat', routes.heartbeat);
app.get('/courses', routes.courses);

// Tools
app.get('/point', routes.point);

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

This is using express 2.5, I wouldn't mind migrating over to 3 if need be.

Comment: Show us a little bit more code / how you configured your set up. Does it give any errors?

Comment: Just added some app.js code. I'm on express 2.5, but I could move to 3 if need be.